# custom ActionBar's behavior on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Situation: In my app (minSDK:14) I have a сustomized `ActionBar`. In my `customView` a have an `EditText` and some `Buttons`.

The `ActionBar` itself has tabs and serves to navigate between `Fragments` hosted by a `ViewPager`. The `customView` is located above the tabs. I have 2 possible setup scenarios (depending on app's settings):

1). Tabs use icons, and in that case the Theme defined as "`sMain`" is applied to the `Activity`

2). Tabs use text, and the `Theme.Holo` is applied to the `Activity`

**The problem when the screen is rotated to landscape:**

**scenario #1:** the whole `ActionBar` becomes 1-line. Tab area now takes the whole screen width and my `customView` just gets positioned on the right side and overlaps the tabs. This behavior completely messes up my UI.

**scenario #2:** the `ActionBar` also becomes 1-line, but now the tabs are "stacked" as a drop-down menu on the left side and the `customView` takes the rest of the screen width. That also messes up my UI because:

-Tab background of the Holo Theme has a different design than my `customView` which is not designed to be just beside the tab menu

-Tabs are now represented by text, which can be longer or shorter and my customView's width changes whenever a tab is changed (so the text becomes the room it needs)

**The question:**  is that possible to force the `ActionBar` to always be 2-lines, so my customView has its space? If not, any other solutions?

In case it matters, below is my ActionBar's setup and the corresponding Theme:

```
        actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_main);
            // working with customView's subviews
```

Styles:

```
 <style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mTabAreaBackground</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>
    <style name="sGunView" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mTabAreaBackground</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mTabAreaBackground" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#0d0d0d</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: just in case someone is looking for an answer: I got a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202161/modify-actionbars-appearance-at-runtime