# modify actionBar's appearance at runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application I use an `ActionBar` (nether ABS nor the support action bar! minSDK = 14). The user may choose whether to use icon or text-based Tabs.
I'm still facing some issues while handling the screen rotation. Basically, I have a `customView` set on the top (using `getActionBar.setCustomView()`) in which some text and control elements are placed. In portrait mode everything works fine, but rotating the device messes up my UI.

I'm posting some screenshots to illustrate the issue (*icons changed to dummy*).

The problem here is that the tabs get stacked, **I found no way to force the `ActionBar` to stay 2-lined.** If you know how to do it, I'd be really thankful for a solution.

So based upon the fact the `ActionBar` will stay single-line in landscape mode, I tried at least to customize the background behind the tab text to match my design and it worked.

*The real issue starts with icon mode.* Portrait:

[image]

Everything's fine here. Rotating the device:

[image]

So as you can see, there's NO SPACE for the `customView` and the tab area to be in one line. But since the android dev team believes their `ActionBar` is smarter then us, the system totally disregards the lack of space, presses the tabs together and places the `customView` to the right, causing it to overlap the tabs. This completely messes up my UI, and **I'm looking for any possible solution** (for some reasons I'm forced to use the `ActionBar` and not something else).

If you need some code related to setting up the ActionBar, I'll post it, though it's pretty much a default implementation so I think this is irrelevant to the question. I'm asking about some basic ideas how to solve the described issue.

Comment: Are the icons (question marks) (supposed to be) part of the `ActionBar` or are they independent?

Comment: I use NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS for my actionBar and also implement the onTabListener, this works together with a ViewPager. So they are part of the AB

Comment: The only way I know is to create the entire View that will be your `ActionBar` within a .xml and then reference it via `getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.yourID)`. Now if this messes up your portrait mode, try using split ActionBar, by adding the `<meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS" android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />` to your `<activity>` definition in your Manifest. Hopefully this would fix your problem in both modes.

Comment: well I'm doing pretty much the same now. I'm using `setCustomView()` and reference the layout that you can see (some text and buttons). AB is also initialized with `getActionBar()`. I've tried the `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` attribute but with no effect at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to force the tabs to appear on two-lines in both portrait and landscape mode. `ActionBarImpl#setHasEmbeddedTabs(boolean)` controls whether the tabs will be embedded (shown as a drop-down list) or not. Through reflection, we'll pass the boolean `false` to it.

See if the following helps:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();

// Set navigation mode      
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Initialize and add tabs      
for (int i=1; i <= 20; i++) {
    Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText("Tab " + i);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
}

Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = null;

try {
    setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = mActionBar.getClass().
                                    getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", 
                                                        boolean.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);

try {
    setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(mActionBar, false);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you saved my day, thanks! Two more questions: I had to remove  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` from the manifest to get your code working. Why that? Could you explain how exactly this works? As far as I understood the ActionBar has the `setHasEmbeddedTabs` method which is private to the system and here you explicitly tell the system to use that. Is it correct?

Comment: @Droidman First Q: `configChanges="orientation"` prevents the OS from destroying and recreating your Activity on orientation change (you already know this). The flag indicates that the developer is handling orientation change internally, through Activity's `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method. But, `ActionBar` has its own `onConfigurationChanged(...)` method and guess what it does: it calls `setHasEmbeddedTabs()`... (contd.)

Comment: @Droidman (contd.)... So, if you want to keep `configChanges` in the manifest, you'll need to override your activity's `onConfigurationChanged(...)` and call the reflection code (`Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = null;` onwards) after the `super` call. Currently, I suppose you call this code in `onCreate(..)`. By removing `configChanges`, the `onCreate(..)` method is called whenever the orientation changes, and we're okay.

Comment: @Droidman Second Q: Reflection is sort of a last resort. It is also much slower than calling a method directly. As you said in the question - `android dev team believes their ActionBar is smarter then us` - when there is no customization option available to us, we turn to java Reflection api. Since this is not a public method, its implementation may have changed from one version to another. So, you should verify that this method exists (and functions similarly) in all of your app's supported versions.

Comment: @Droidman `Is it correct?` Well, look at these: [Link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101187/are-there-problems-with-using-reflection) | [Link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123956/why-should-i-use-reflection).